# Invalid Argument error on the python code

Tags: python, data-analysis

I am beginner to python, and I have this code to decompress log file, but I have the error Invalid argument. I don't know why I got this error, in my opinion, I think it is because the log file is too big, cause I am scanning a log file which is 2gb file. But I have no idea how to fix the error. Please help, thank you. And below is my code with the error:

```
import glob
import gzip
import os
import pymysql
import logging
 # path to gz directory
GZ_DIR = '/Users/kiya/Desktop/mysql/csv'
# Database Infomation
DB_HOST='locahost'
DB_USER='dbuser'
DB_PASS='dbPassword'
DB_NAME='dbname'
LOGFILE="exception.log"
def csv_reader(file, header=False):
    import csv
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        if header:
            next(reader)
        for row in reader:
            yield row
def import_sql(filename, dbHostName, dbUser, dbPassword, databaseName):
    db = pymysql.connect(host=dbHostName,
                         user=dbUser,
                         password=dbPassword,
                         db=databaseName,
                         charset='utf8')

    for row in csv_reader(filename, False):
        # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
        with db.cursor() as cursor:
            if row[3] == "THREAT" and row[4] == "url":
                sql = ("INSERT INTO PADIAGDB.url ("
                       "Domain,Receive_Time,Serial,Type,Threat_Content_Type,"
                       "Config_Version,Generate_Time,Source_address,Destination_address,"
                       "NAT_Source_IP,NAT_Destination_IP,Rule,Source_User,"
                       "Destination_User,Application,Virtual_System,Source_Zone,"
                       "Destination_Zone,Inbound_Interface,Outbound_Interface,Log_Action,"
                       "Time_Logged,Session_ID,Repeat_Count,Source_Port,Destination_Port,"
                       "NAT_Source_Port,NAT_Destination_Port,Flags,IP_Protocol,Action,"
                       "URL_Filename,Threat_Content_Name,Category,Severity,Direction,"
                       "Sequence_Number,Action_Flags,Source_Country,Destination_Country,"
                       "cpadding,contenttype,pcap_id,filedigest,cloud,url_idx,user_agent,"
                       "filetype,xff,referer,sender,subject,recipient,reportid,"
                       "dg_hier_level_1,dg_hier_level_2,dg_hier_level_3,dg_hier_level_4,"
                       "Virtual_System_Name,Device_Name,file_url )"
                       ""
                       "VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,"
                       "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,"
                       "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s"
                       "); ")
            elif row[3] == "SYSTEM":
                sql = ("INSERT INTO PADIAGDB.system ("
                       "Domain,Receive_Time,Serial,Type,Threat_Content_Type,Config_Version,"
                       "Generate_Time,Virtual_System,Event_ID,Object,fmt,id,module,Severity,"
                       "Description,Sequence_Number,Action_Flags,dg_hier_level_1,"
                       "dg_hier_level_2,dg_hier_level_3,dg_hier_level_4,Virtual_System_Name,"
                       "Device_Name )"
                       ""
                       "VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,"
                       "%s,%s,%s );")
            else:
                continue
            try:
                cursor.execute('SET foreign_key_checks = 0')
                # Execute the SQL command
                r = cursor.execute(sql, row)

                #Commit your changes in the database
                cursor.execute('SET foreign_key_checks = 1')
                db.commit()
            except Exception as e:
                logging.exception(e)
                db.rollback()
     # disconnect from server
    db.close()
gz_files = (gz for gz in glob.glob(os.path.join(GZ_DIR, '*.gz')))
for gz_file in gz_files:
    with gzip.open(gz_file, 'rb') as in_file:
        s = in_file.read()
    sql_file = gz_file[:-3]
    sql_file = sql_file[:-4] + '.csv'
    with open(sql_file, 'wb') as out_file:
        out_file.write(s)
    import_sql(out_file, DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME)
    os.remove(sql_file)
```

This is the error I got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kiya/Desktop/mysql/csv/sql3.py", line 180, in <module>
    out_file.write(s)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: try readlines() and writelines() to write in batches

Comment: @shahaf I did as you say, and I got this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kiya/Desktop/mysql/csv/sql3.py", line 183, in <module>
    import_sql(out_file, DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME)
  File "/Users/kiya/Desktop/mysql/csv/sql3.py", line 38, in import_sql
    for row in csv_reader(filename, False):
  File "/Users/kiya/Desktop/mysql/csv/sql3.py", line 18, in csv_reader
    with open(file, "r") as f:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BufferedWriter

Comment: `readlines()` and `writelines()` are not suitable for binary files, only for text files, so @shahaf should not have suggested those, but the principle stands - try splitting the data into chunks.

Comment: @cdarke works fine with my binary files...

Comment: @shahaf: maybe you're on python2, in python 3 you will get the error shown by the OP.

Comment: @cdarke I'm on python 3.6, anyway you are right in the sense that it using `readlines` although it would work, it is a monkey patch solution...

Answer (score 1):

for reading big files, you will have to read and write in chucks, try smth like (draft)

```
fr = open(input_file, 'rb')
fw = open(output_file, 'wb')
while True:
    chunk = fr.read(1024)  
    if not chunk:
        break
    fw.write(chunk)
fr.close() 
fw.close()
```

you can use context mangers of course aka `with`